# Cannot Visit .Onion Website with CURL

Tags: php, curl, tor, php-curl

I'm using a class that Connects into Tor Proxy Port I can visit http://check.torproject.org and says that I'm using Tor Browser, But when I'm trying to visit a .onion Website I get blank page.

I used this [class](https://gist.github.com/sxss/acfdce73976f219a6695)

Comment: You should definitely add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It fails to load `.onion` addresses because it uses the curl proxy type of `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5` instead of `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME` which would use the Tor SOCKS proxy to also resolve DNS addresses.

You would need to change:

```
curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5 );
```

to:

```
curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME );
```

Beyond that, the example class doesn't give you the ability to customize your requests at all.

I have written a Tor cURL wrapper class called [`TorCurlWrapper`](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/src/TorCurlWrapper.php) (examples [here](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/CurlWrapper.php) and [here](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/CurlCountry.php)) which is part of a larger Tor PHP library called [TorUtils](https://github.com/dapphp/torutils).  It wraps curl in an easy to use set of functions and ensures that requests can only be made through Tor and takes care of setting the proxy type properly and will fail if it is not supported (really old curl versions).

You can download it standalone or install using Composer by running `composer require dapphp/torutils`.